# AC WiFi: performances are good from Internet speed but poor within the LAN itself

Tags: lan, nas, bandwidth, 802.11ac, wifi-transfer

Recently I put a [Netgear A6210 USB WiFi adapter](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-adapters/a6210.aspx) on my laptop to connect with my ISP's 802.11ac 5GHz router. The router is alleged to have a speed of 1,734 Mbps, but the Netgear shows its maximum link speed capability as 866.5 Mbps.

Now my ISP says my maximum Internet bandwidth is 108 Mbps (soon they will do the upgrade to FTTH technology to reach 1000 Mbps). I can stream 4K videos from YouTube flawlessly, with no buffering issue (I made sure to select 2160p 4K from YouTube's settings). When I do an internet speedtest from [www.speedtest.net](https://www.speedtest.net), the test shows an average speed of 100 Mbps (can vary from 93 Mbps to 100 Mbps).

The modem also has USB 3.1 ports, where I connected an external USB 3.0 capable external HDD (there are no other devices connected). The status LED on the USB3 HDD is blue coloured (if is connected to an USB 2.0 port, instead the status LED is white coloured).

Today I tried to streaming a 4K video file (MPEG-4, Bit rate 43.0 Mb/s) from the mentioned USB3 HDD connected to the modem, by using VLC. The playing of such video file was an unbearable continuous buffering! Plase notice that my laptop, on AC WiFi, was the only device connected to the modem. No problem if I play this 4K video file when the USB3 HDD is directly connected to the laptop.

So I also tried to download a file from the LAN USB3 HDD: a 405 MB zip file, many times: the average speed (stable and almost constant) was of 10 MB/s, which are equal to 80 Mbps.

I am guessing that there is a bottleneck somewhere: could be the external USB HDD? It is a Toshiba HDD, which as I've said is properly functioning @USB 3.0 speed, and furthermore on my laptop I have a Samsung EVO 850 SSD connected to an internal SATA III port.

What can I do to make sure that the culprit is the LAN HDD? There is something else that can I check to properly test my LAN speed? At the moment I cannot test the laptop connected to the ethernet port of the modem (the ethernet adapter of laptop is 1 Gpbs, like the ethernet ports of the modem) since I don't have a proper ethernet cable.

Comment: What protocol did you use for the VLC streaming? Did you mount the share via SMB and then use VLC to play the file as if it was local?

Comment: Coue of things - it could be that the router is simply not powerful enough to read the HDD at the desired speeds. Also, outside lab like environments the advertised WIFI speed is never the same as the throughput you will get. Try using a cable to eliminate WIFI noise as a contributing factor.